# The code needed to be joined in order to get a output needed

Tags: python, expression, logical-operators, brackets

CODE SNIPPET 1: generates all possible set of brackets

```
class Parenthesis(object):
    def __init__(self, parens):
        self.parens = parens
        self.my_valid_parens = {
                                1: ['()'],
                                2: ['()','()'],
                               }


    def generate_valid_paren(self):
        if self.parens <= 2:
            return self.my_valid_parens[self.parens]

        i = 3
        while i <= self.parens:
            new_set = []
            for each in self.my_valid_parens[i-1]:
                new_set += set([each + '()', '()' + each, '(' + each + ')'])
            self.my_valid_parens[i] = list(new_set)
            i += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = 4
    p = Parenthesis(num)
    p.generate_valid_paren()
    print("linesep")
    print (p.my_valid_parens[num])
```

The problem with code 1 is that the output is generated twice after 5th output.
How can this be corrected ?

CODE SNIPPET 2: generates all possible combination of values by changing the logical '&' and '|' operator

```
def insert():

        operands = [ 0, 0, 0, 1]
        type(operands)
        operators = ['|', '&']
        type(operators)
        for opers in product(operators, repeat=len(operands) - 1):
            formula = [str(operands[0])]
            for op, operand in zip(opers, operands[1:]):
                formula.extend([op, str(operand)])
            formula = ' '.join(formula)
            print('{} = {}'.format(formula, eval(formula)))
            print("  ")
```

Can anyone suggest me a way to join these codes so that the output could be something like this ( ( 0 | 0 ) | ( 0 & 1 ) ) = 0 i.e. the expression variables have all possible generated brackets i.e. obtained above ?

Answer (score 0):

for the first part of question, Duplicate values in the valid_paren dict causing pattern to get repeated after 5 occurrence.
below will not return the duplicate pattern.

```
class Parenthesis(object):
    def __init__(self, parens):
        self.parens = parens
        self.my_valid_parens = {
                                1: ['()'],
                                2: ['()'],
                               }


    def generate_valid_paren(self):
        if self.parens <= 2:
            return self.my_valid_parens[self.parens]
        i = 3
        while i <= self.parens:
            new_set = []

            for each in self.my_valid_parens[i-1]:
                new_set += set([each + '()', '()' + each, '(' + each + ')'])
            self.my_valid_parens[i] = list(new_set)
            i += 1
            print(self.my_valid_parens)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = 4
    p = Parenthesis(num)
    p.generate_valid_paren()
    print("linesep")
    print (p.my_valid_parens[num])
```

For second part I am still not able to understand what you are trying to achieve, can you give example from out received from above code.

Comment: for the second code if you can tell me how you want the output, e.g. output of first code is '((()))', '(())()', '()(())', '()()()', '(()())'. how you want to place the second codes output in first one?

Comment: i need the outputs like this ( a | ( b | c )) | ( d ) where a, b, c, d can be 0 or 1